# Using nonlocal inside exec

Tags: python, python-3.x, cpython, python-exec, python-nonlocal

Why does the following code:

```
exec("""
a = 3
def b():
  nonlocal a
  a = a + 1
b() #error occurs even without this call
print(a)
"""
)
```

)

give this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 4
SyntaxError: no binding for nonlocal 'a' found
```

This is some more text to satisfy the text/code ratio.

Comment: `a` isn't in a function scope, you'd want `global a` instead

Comment: You'd get the same error with the same code written out explicitly, rather than using `exec` on a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `nonlocal` statement looks for the variable you name in an enclosing function namespace (and raises an error if there is no such variable in any such namespace). If there is no enclosing function, you don't want `nonlocal`. If you want a variable at the top level, you want to use the `global` statement instead.